# Introductory course on interpreting GOES-R satellite images?

Tags: weather-satellites, reference-request

As you might be aware, [GOES-R](https://www.goes-r.gov) is a very rich satellite system that delivers near real-time weather information for the globe. There are at least 16 channels reported ([this site](https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/GOES/index.php) is great for monitoring them).

I am looking for an introductory course on satellite image for amateur weather analysis, ideally based on GOES-R. The training offered in [GOES-R website](https://www.goes-r.gov/users/training/gsm.html) seems directed to practitioners. There are some guides around (NOAA site above, for instance, offers a "Quick Guide" for every channel, e.g. [Channel 13](https://www.star.nesdis.noaa.gov/GOES/documents/ABIQuickGuide_Band13.pdf) but that seems also too advanced for a novice to understand).

Is anyone aware of an introductory course on satellite image interpretation? Naturally, I am looking for an online course, ideally free of charge. If based on GOES-R, the better.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous short modules offered by UCAR's COMET/METED website: https://www.meted.ucar.edu/training_detail.php

Modules specific to GOES-R include (but aren't limited to):

- GOES-R/JPSS test cases for [convection initiation](https://www.meted.ucar.edu/training_module.php?id=10041#.X6LYnIhKhqM) and [wildfires](https://www.meted.ucar.edu/training_module.php?id=10034).
- [Advanced Baseline imager](https://www.meted.ucar.edu/training_module.php?id=1325#.X6LY_IhKhqM)
- [A satellite foundational course](http://meted.ucar.edu/training_module.php?id=1301#.X6LZJ4hKhqM)

There are 19 courses with GOES-R in the title.

Comment: Thanks, awesome site! Plenty of material. The ones you mention are targeted to skill level 1 or 2, 0 being the lowest, but will look at the resources to see if I can find something for me. I will leave the question open to see if someone comes with more resources.